# Correct way to use bash to replace text in files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, preg-replace

I have a config file filled with settings. Like a bunch of settings. I would like to know how to automate the replacement for example:

I have `LF_ALERT_TO = ""` and I would like to add an e-mail to that.

Question two:

Can I use opts to to grab an e-mail for that? Example:

```
./run --email e.mail@here.com
```

My current code layout:

```
wget http://www.configserver.com/free/csf.tgz
tar -zxvf csf.tgz
cd csf
./install.sh
(modifiy values in /etc/csf/csf.conf
```

Comment: what's the expected output? `LF_ALERT_TO = "e.mail@here.com"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use sed for that task, assuming the email is stored in a `$EMAILVAR` environment variable:

```
sed -i -e "s/\\(LF_ALERT_TO[ \\t]*=[ \\t]*\"\\)[^\"]*\"/\\1$EMAILVAR\"/" config.txt
```

Here we tell sed to replace a string that contains (in order):

1. `LF_ALERT_TO`
2. a sequence of spaces and/or tabs (`[ \t]*`)
3. `=`
4. another sequence of spaces and/or tabs
5. `"`
6. a sequence of characters that aren't `"` (`[^"]*`)
7. `"`

Items 1-5 are placed between backslashed parenthesis. This forms a capture group, so what is matched by them is stored in an auxiliary "variable" called `\1`.

We then generate a string consisting of:

1. `\1`, ie. what matched steps 1-5 above
2. The desired email
3. A closing `"` (because it wasn't captured)

We use the `-i` flag in the command to tell sed to edit the file in place (ie. execute the commands using `config.txt` as the input, then store the output on top of the same file).

Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: Alright. I think I got it. How hard would it be to place a VARIABLE in where e-mail is? And if I wanted to find and replace a number I just have to modify step 6 where it looks for the string inside?

Comment: Not hard at all, replace the single-quotes with double quotes, and instead of "someone@somewhere.com", place "$EMAILVAR". I'll edit the post for clarity. As for step 6, exactly, you can place a regex pattern there to match whatever you want (like `[0-9]*` for numbers). =)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. When changing from single to double quotes, you must also backslash the internal double-quotes. And also it is a good idea to backslash the original backslashes =)

Answer (score 2):

if you want `LF_ALERT_TO = "e.mail@here.com"` in your csf.conf

```
sed -i 's/LF_ALERT_TO = ""/LF_ALERT_TO = "e.mail@here.com"/g' csf.conf
```

should work.

if you want to pass email as variable:

```
kent$  cat csf.conf
foo
LF_ALERT_TO = ""
foo
bar
whatever
kent$  em="e.mail@here.com" 

kent$  sed  "s/LF_ALERT_TO = \"\"/LF_ALERT_TO = \"$em\"/g" csf.conf 
foo
LF_ALERT_TO = "e.mail@here.com"
foo
bar
whatever
```

with `sed -i "..." csf.conf will change the original file.`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to replace in one file? If so, you may consider using vim.
search/replace command is the following:

```
%s/LF_ALERT_TO = ""/LF_ALERT_TO = "email@email.com"/g
```

If you need to replace in a bunch of files you may consider using the following command:

```
find path_to_find -iname "filemask" -exec sed -i 's/LF_ALERT_TO = ""/LF_ALERT_TO = "email@email.com/g" {} \;
```